# How can i loop through request()-> all() post (Laravel) data?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to loop through the request:: all() array and return the values, but instead, am getting just the token.

This is what i am currently trying, but its returning just the form token

```
This is the JSON 

1   "microwaves"
2   "has enough energy to remove electrons from atoms"
3   "thyroid"
4   "stop immediately when switch is turned off"
5   "travel in a straight line"
6   "xrays and electrons"
7   "the radiation that hits the imaging plate"
8   "American limits and radiation allowances"
9   "genetic effects, those passed room parent to child"
10  "maximize distance from the source"
_token  "ABB88ZTnMAQ9DkuHb546aubz9ufK2SZQWxaKgm7w"
```

```
public function store(){
  $data = request()->all();

  foreach ($data as $key) {
    return $key;
  }
``
```

Comment: use `return $request->all();`

Comment: Yeah, i have don that but while am looping using the foreach it returns just the _token

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot to put `Request $request` in the store parameters:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {    
    $data = $request->all();

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

---

And if you are trying to get the whole request, except the `_token`, then use this:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {    
    $data = $request->except('_token');

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. I want to test in loop that value is image or not. How can I do that?